# bag composite-element from subselect

Tags: nhibernate, subquery

I have a query I want to be able to use to populate a composite-element property of a class. I have created this:

```
<bag name="Relationships">
  <subselect>
    select count(RelationID) as Relations, Relationship, EntityID from rcs.tblRelation_Link group by Relationship, EntityID
  </subselect>
  <key column="EntityID" />
  <composite-element class="Relationship">
    <many-to-one class="Lookup" name="RelationType" column="Relationship" />
    <property name="Count" type="int" column="Relations" />
  </composite-element>
</bag>
```

Which generates a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT relationsh0_.EntityID     as EntityID0_,
   relationsh0_.Relationship as Relation2_0_,
   relationsh0_.Relations    as Relations0_
FROM   Relationships relationsh0_
WHERE  relationsh0_.EntityID = 'guidvalue'
```

So clearly this is not the way to do what I am trying to do. Does anyone have a suggestion of how to use a query to populate elements like this short of creating a view on the database side? I would ideally like to keep everything in the app so it is obvious where it is coming from.

I may not have explained this completely so please do let me know if you I can clarify anything!

Thanks!

Comment: have you been able to get it to work yet?

Comment: I do not remember the details honestly as it was a long time ago and I am working on totally different technology now.  However, I vaguely recall that this never worked like this.  I ended up having to restructure the hbm file entirely and approach differently.